# Unable to set up necessary files for running Yolov5. Unable to locate files

Tags: tracking, modulenotfounderror, yolov5, file-not-found

My project is to make a programm that is able to track a badminton shuttlecock. I have prevoiusly been using opencv to track it. However, it was unsuccesful. As a result I am now trying to use a single frame object detection. More specificly yolov5. I was setting up the required files to run yolov5 and cam across this issue when testing if I had all the files.

This is the code I ran...

```
import torch
from IPython.display import Image  # for displaying images
from utils.google_utils import gdrive_download  # for downloading models/datasets
print('torch %s %s' % (torch.__version__, torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0) if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'CPU'))
```

which resulted in this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zhilu\Yolov5 Stuff\Yolov5 TEST.py", line 3, in <module>
    from utils.google_utils import gdrive_download  # for downloading models/datasets
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.google_utils'
```

It seems like it was not able to find the file.

I made sure the directory was correct, even confirming the files was there by going through file explorer. I looked at multiple differnt tutorial, but none of them seem to cover this issue.